# How to align annotation to the edge of whole figure in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I know how to align annotation respective to the plotting area (using xref="paper"). I want to place the annotation to right bottom corner of the whole figure. Absolute or relative offset does not work, since the width of the margin outside the plotting area is changing among several figures, depending on their content. Is there a way how to do it?
Thanks a ton.

Edit: Example code

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], title="Try panning or zooming!")

fig.add_annotation(text="Absolutely-positioned annotation",
                  xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=0.3, y=0.3, showarrow=False)

fig.show()
```

This annotation is positioned respectively to the origin of the plot, not respectively to the plot edges.
[image]

Comment: Pls post the code you are using and the incorrect figure

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
fig = px.scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], title="Try panning or zooming!")

fig.add_annotation(text="Absolutely-positioned annotation",
                   xref='paper', yref='paper',
                   x=0.95, y=-0.1, showarrow=False)
```

[image]

Comment: From Plotly web: Positioning in paper coordinates is not done in absolute pixel terms, but rather in terms relative to a coordinate system defined with an origin (0,0) at (layout.margin.l, layout.margin.b) and a point (1,1) at (layout.width-layout.margin.r, layout.height-layout.margin.t). In other words, paper coordinates are related to the position of the plotting area, which is exactly what I don't want. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated. You can set 'paper' coordinates to outside the plot setting x and/or y to just outside the [0,1] range. Paper coordinates are not relative to the plot, but rather to the entire figure including margins.

Comment: I dare to disagree. Coordinates x=0, y=0 places the annotation to the left down corner of the plotting area when "paper" coordinates are set. I can use it to place my annotation to the corner of the whole image of course, but I'll need to find the desired coordinates manually. Maybe I wrote my question confusingly.
I actually want to recycle one function to place annotation to image corner of several plots and one set of coordinates for one plot won't work for the others, because their margins have different width.